# How to prove that there must be a bijection between two different implementations of the same function

Tags: functions, logic

This question emerged in a conversation with a neuroscientist this morning, in which I wondered aloud whether one could prove that if there exists two different implementations of a function then there must exist a bijection between the implementations.

This would be useful for instance, if you wanted to train an artificial neural network to actual sensory input of an organism and ask it to produce precisely the same motor output as the model organism does.

Then with the help of such a theorem, you'd be able to show that while the two functions have the same mappings and are ostensibly implemented differently, there does exist a direct correspondence between what is being accomplished in with linear algebra in your model and the chemical computations in the real organism.

For example, take the function

$$F(x) = \sin x$$

and take the function

$$G(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{\Gamma(2n+2)}$$

For any $x$ we know that $F(x) = G(x)$.

Provided we do not define $\sin x \equiv G(x)$, i.e. perhaps we define $\sin \theta$ implicitly as:

- $\forall x,y,r \in \mathbb{R}:\big\{ \frac{y}{x}= \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos \theta} \implies x^2 + y^2 = r^2 \big \}$ and then prove that the mappings $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ are uniquely defined by this assertion.

Is it possible to show that the two "implementations" of $\sin x$ must have a bijection. That somehow the formal machinery that allows $\sin x$ to emerge from my implicit definition is actually equivalent to the formal machinery that enables $\sin x$ to emerge from the Taylor series?

What I do not want to show is that the mappings are the same. That I know how to show.

What I want to show and am struggling to express is that the actual formal implementations of the functions are the same. Perhaps both definitions require certain things to happen underground that are symmetric. I don't know.

Can you help me

1. Express this idea
2. Tell me what has been thought about it before (perhaps in theory of computation?)
3. Do so in a way that a pre rigorous guy can appreciate

Comment: Are you essentially asking that if I have a function $F(x)$ and I have two different algorithms to compute $F(x)$, then there must be a correspondence between each "step" in the two algorithms? As in, if I wrote down side-by-side the steps whereby to compute $F(x)$ using the two algorithms, I could draw lines connecting which step corresponds to which step between the two algorithms?

Comment: Possibly. I'm not sure. In terms of formal math I might mean a correspondence in the theorems and definitions between two functions. The theorems themselves essentially develop a definition of the functions in terms of a formal theory. In practical terms, then yes, I mean two algorithms.

Comment: I know very little of the details of formal logic or proof theory, but if I'm understanding you right, it seems like your theorem is false since you can always take *more* steps than necessary to perform some task (or define some object). To get to my mailbox, I could go straight there, or walk around my house and *then* go there. If I'm defining a set as $S = \{1,2,3\}$ I could also add in a redundancy and define it as $S = \{1,2,3\} \cap \mathbb{R}$. You can always make something more inefficient.

Comment: Even if you are making it more inefficient, wouldn't it be possible to avoid the redundancy by folding the redundant parts into a net effect. Ex: if one movement sequence is $\{+1, -1, +1\}$ and another $\{+1\}$, we simply consider $+1, -1$ as one step and $+1$ as being formally $0+1$. Maybe what I am saying is that we can always "continuously deform" one definition of a function into an functionally equivalent but definitionally separate function.

Comment: We just find the right partitioning of the algorithm to equivalence.

Comment: What you mentioned in the question reminds me a bit of some of the issues addressed by [Homotopy Type Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_type_theory#Equality). [This introduction](http://www.carloangiuli.com/blog/homotopy-type-theory-univalent-foundations-of-mathematics/) may be a bit more friendly.

Comment: Thanks. So these questions are very modern?

Comment: Yes I looked at homotopy type theory and I am pretty sure it is precisely the construct I need to investigate this issue. If eventually $\sin$ can be implemented with $\lambda$ functions then that would be the starting point to showing their underlying functional equivalence. And the notion of homotopical paths, just awesome. I'm going to go through this.